# Typing localhost in browser should send me to main page of my PHP project

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

I have a PHP project which has many files. I have configured it properly and it's working.

But I want that whenever I type (only) `localhost` in my browser, it should lead to the main page of my project.
Right now, the scenario is whenever I do that, it shows the php directory like this:

```
Index of /
adddet.php
client/ 
dbconn.php
deldet.php
login.php
main.php
```

Comment: by default browsers expect and index file which you don't have here. rename main.php to index.php and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I will just assume you are using Apache as your web server.

Rename main.php to index.php or adjust httpd.conf like follows.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm default.htm index.php index.pl main.php
```

You need to use DirectoryIndex directive under Apache to set a default page other than index.html or index.php.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the rewrite enigne of apache2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /main.php [R,L]
```

Best regards!